# Is there a way to determine the time taken from power on to Windows starting

Tags: boot, bios

I would like to be able to tell how long it takes to get from power on to windows starting.
Is there a way of determining this retrospectively (ie once windows has started)?
Does the BIOS/CMOS hold a last boot time?
Would it be possible to tell from RDTSC how long a machine has been running for and subtract the windows boot time?

Answer (score 0):

You might try [BootTimer](http://www.planetsoft.org/) or [BootRacer](http://www.greatis.com/bootracer/index.html) to see either of them will do what you want.

I don't believe you can determine this after Windows is started. I'm not aware of any BIOS that stores the last boot time. But on any modern machine, if the time between power on to calling the OS boot loader (essentially the time it takes to run the [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test) routines) takes longer than a few seconds, something is wrong.

Are you trying to do this programmatically to get the accurate amount of time that the machine has been online and usable? The inaccuracy resulting from the few seconds that POST takes doesn't seem like it would make a significant difference. If you're timing for benchmarking or optimization purposes, either of these two utilities should work for you.

Comment: We actually have a problem where some machines are taking minutes to get through the POST so I was hoping to create a way of detecting them all so we can investigate. So the timing does not need to be particularly accurate - just good enough to distinguish between a few seconds and a couple of minutes

Comment: Maybe someone else will have an idea about how to get times to compare. The best I can do is suggest fixes like turning off comprehensive RAM checks, optimizing the order the BIOS searches for boot devices (especially turning off long searches for network boot devices), making sure any applicable "Fast Boot" option is enabled, and disabling floppy drive seeks. I've also seen auto-detection of hard drives slow down POST--check any cable or connections and consider storing drive parameters (and setting non-existent drives to None) in the CMOS instead of leaving it set to Auto. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions as to what might be causing the slow downs. Very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Get the time since power on from GetTickCount(). Then get the timestamp of a file Windows touches at boot (windows\bootstat.dat for example). Code is below. On my machine it says 16 seconds which sounds accurate.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    struct __stat64 st;
    _stat64("c:\\windows\\bootstat.dat", &st);

    return printf("%d\n", st.st_mtime - (time(NULL) - GetTickCount()/1000));
}
```

Comment: Does GetTickCount measure the time from power on or from when Windows starts? MSDN is a bit vague as it says from when the system starts...

Comment: Just tried pausing the bootloader, and it still prints '16'. So GetTickCount seems to report time since Windows starts. But a variation of the idea may work: record time of shutdown, then time of startup (it only works if the user does a restart, not a shutdown).

Comment: I was thinking of using RDTSC instead of GetTickCount which I think should give the time since switch on. I just need to work out the easiest way of converting the number into seconds. The bootstat.dat idea is a nice easy way of getting windows start time though